# searchview not expanding full width

Tags: android, searchview, layoutparams

Basically I want the searachview to expand and collapse when there is a imagebutton behind which should disappear when icon is clicked  and view should appear when searchview collapses.

I am using search view not in action bar .When i click on the search icon it expands only half the screen but it should expand complete width but should wrap_content when I close the searchview.

```
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
```

I also tried :

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = searchview.getLayoutParams();
params.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

But I am getting error here **setLayoutParams** it says **"add to cast"**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At first you're getting an exception, because if you look into search_view.xml located in

> \Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-18\data\res\layout\

You'll find out that SearchView is basically simple LinearLayout merging several widgets together. That's why you are getting class cast exception. Instead of

```
android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = searchview.getLayoutParams();
```

use

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) searchview.getLayoutParams();
```

or just import correct class and then you can simply use this

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

                      ...

LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) searchview.getLayoutParams();
```

than you can use LayoutParams without any prefix.

But I don't think that setting `LayoutParams` to wrap content will help. I would wrap your `SearchView` and `ImageButton` to `RelativeLayout`, where you could specify view position relative to the other views. Then simply set `SearchView` width to fill parent, so it could fill remaining space.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the XML-attribute android:maxWidth like described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#attr_android:maxWidth

I am using the SearchView from actionbarsherlock and used the corresponding java-method to stretch the SearchView over the available width of the actionbar.

Comment: searchView.setMaxWidth(findViewById(R.id.layout).getMeasuredWidth());

Answer (score 1):

[image: first screenshot]

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_b"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_scan"
        android:icon="@drawable/scan_b"
        android:title="Scan"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add_cusomer"
        android:icon="@drawable/add_cust_b"
        android:title="Add Customer"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />

</menu>

After Clicking on Search icon:
```

[image: screenshot after clicking on search]

Answer (score 0):

Try this according to your needs but dont think to work on your own button, you can move default searchButton to right side with giving wrap_content width parameter and then when you click to search set width to match_parent then again when you close it set width to wrap_content

Use your searchView child of RelativeLayout and be sure about right LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/counter_text_color" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLeftMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_drawer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar_logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="YOUR "
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonRightMenu" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRightMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_settings" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and at your class

```
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.buttonLeftMenu);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.buttonRightMenu);
        searchView.setLayoutParams(params);

    }
});

searchView.setOnCloseListener(new OnCloseListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.buttonRightMenu);
        searchView.setLayoutParams(params);

        return false;
    }
});
```